# Magento Custome Error Page for database connection fail

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, magento, exception

I need to redirect users to a custom page if magento system encounters a any issue with database`[any sql state error]`.

So far I was unable to find a way to do it. Should I override any core class/methods or can I do it using `.htaccess` file. if I have to override core class/method, which model method should I have to rewrite.

Comment: check `errors/processor.php`. it processes all types of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe better way would be just edit error page template in /errors/default/report.phtml to inform customers about problems. It will also show Your content when any php error will occur.

Comment: Kamil, i found this page [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/configure_magento_error_page) which describe a situation little bit similar to my issue. I need a seperate page like this to show when a server error occours, not in http errors like 404